# How to simplify this code using cycle

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml

Hi I have this code which simply show/hide some absolute positioned divs. This code is ok but very long. How can I simplify this code? Some cycle is way, but I don´t know how dynamically write this.
I mean this is easy question.

JQUERY code:

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $("#vysuv_obal_1").hover(function() {
            $("#vysuv_1").fadeIn(1500);
            $("#vysuv_2").fadeOut(750);
            $("#vysuv_3").fadeOut(750);
            $("#vysuv_4").fadeOut(750);
        });
        $("#vysuv_obal_2").hover(function() {
            $("#vysuv_1").fadeOut(750);
            $("#vysuv_2").fadeIn(1500);
            $("#vysuv_3").fadeOut(750);
            $("#vysuv_4").fadeOut(750);
        });
        $("#vysuv_obal_3").hover(function() {
            $("#vysuv_1").fadeOut(750);
            $("#vysuv_2").fadeOut(750);
            $("#vysuv_3").fadeIn(1500);
            $("#vysuv_4").fadeOut(750);
        });
        $("#vysuv_obal_4").hover(function() {
            $("#vysuv_1").fadeOut(750);
            $("#vysuv_2").fadeOut(750);
            $("#vysuv_3").fadeOut(750);
            $("#vysuv_4").fadeIn(1500);
        });
});
```

HTML:

```
       <div class="ctvrtina_menu_hp_popup" id="vysuv_obal_1">

            <div id="vysuv_1" class="ctvrtina_vysuv" style="display:none;">
                <h2 class="nadpis_menu_hp_popup"><a href="#">Sjezdové lyžování</a></h2>
                <div class="ctvrtina_in2">
                    <a href="#"><span class="polozka_menu_hp_popup">1Sjezdové lyže</span></a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <h2 class="nadpis_menu_hp_popup"><a href="#">Sjezdové lyžování</a></h2>
            <div class="ctvrtina_in">
                <a href="#"><span class="polozka_menu_hp_popup">Sjezdové lyže</span></a>
            </div>
            <a href="#"><span class="tl_menu_hp_popup">Více info</span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="ctvrtina_menu_hp_popup"  id="vysuv_obal_2">

            <div id="vysuv_2" class="ctvrtina_vysuv" style="display:none;">
                <h2 class="nadpis_menu_hp_popup"><a href="#">Sjezdové lyžování</a></h2>
                <div class="ctvrtina_in2">
                    <a href="#"><span class="polozka_menu_hp_popup">2Sjezdové lyže</span></a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <h2 class="nadpis_menu_hp_popup"><a href="#">Běžecké lyžování</a></h2>
            <div class="ctvrtina_in">
                <a href="#"><span class="polozka_menu_hp_popup">Sjezdové lyže</span></a>
            </div>
            <a href="#"><span class="tl_menu_hp_popup">Více info</span></a>
        </div>
```

etc...

class="ctvrtina_vysuv" => absolute positioned div 
class="ctvrtina_menu_hp_popup" => relative positioned div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an attribute to those div's you have like rel="1", rel="2" and so on and add a common class like class="iWantToHover", so when you rewrite the code it should look like this;

```
$(".iWantToHover").hover(function() {
   var r = $(this).attr('rel');
   for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
      if (r === i) {
         $('#vysuv_'+i).fadeIn(750);
      } else {
         $('#vysuv_'+i).fadeOut(750);
      }
   }
}
```

That should give you an idea about it.

This was my first answer...

You can use the jQuery selectors[1] like;

```
$("#vysuv_obal_4").hover(function() {
   $("[id~='#vysuv']").fadeOut(750);
});
```

[1] http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

Comment: With this I hide all absolute divs when I click on 1 div from 4 => I need this 4 times and to each block of code I need add fadeIn.
But yes this is way but still not dynamically.

Comment: Yes this update question is way (I have something similar in javascript) and it can work. I try "Arun P Johny" way without change of HTML and after that I try your question. Thank for tips.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var $ts = $('.ctvrtina_vysuv');
$("#vysuv_1, #vysuv_2, #vysuv_3, #vysuv_4").hover(function(){
    var $vysuv = $(this).find('.ctvrtina_vysuv').finish().fadeIn(1500);
    $('.ctvrtina_vysuv').not($vysuv).finish().fadeOut(750)
})
```